# Show all commits into diff

Tags: git, git-diff

I stuck in a problem is there is any command of git that will show all the commits into a diff and also search for the file if it is there any modification in it.

example like `git log Diff_Number file_name`

If there are multiple commands then please refer me.

Comment: What does it mean to "show all the commits into a diff"? What is "Diff_Number" ?

Comment: See our system work like I'm working on a specific branch and when I'm done with the code then I need to use `arc diff` command to link that code with the phabricator and then Jenkins jobs run for testing the code. So I want the list of all the commits in that diff and check for the file @LasseV.Karlsen so it will give me a diff link in which there is a diff number to check the status

Comment: None of what you just said makes any sense in terms of git. "link"? You have a website that hosts your repository then I guess? "diff number", I still don't know what this means, are you talking about the hash that identifies a commit? Are you asking if you can check if a particular file has been changed in the sequence of commits you're now sending to your CI system? It would be better if you stepped back from the technology and commands and told us what you want to accomplish, not how you think it should be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is as close as you need as possible: https://github.com/eantoranz/difflame

Comment: how this will help I didn't understand this